# Copy File From One Folder to Another Folder in Blob Storage Using SAS (using Azure.Storage.Blobs)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to copy file from source (Templates)folder to another folder(Results) in same container using SAS URI.I am using **Azure.Storage.Blobs** nuget package and **don't want to download it to a local machine during this process**.

I need to do some manupulations in the documents like MailMerge etc while copy it from source to destination folder.For Mail merge i am using SyncFusion.

I done this in my local machine.But i am not sure how do it when we have souce and destination folders in Blob Storage.

Please help me on this

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written and the issues you are running into. Essentially you would need to copy the blob with a new name.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to copy the files from one folder to another folder of same container using SAS token by following structure.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WordDocument document = new WordDocument();

        string sourceUri = "https://<YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>/sourceFolder1/" + "<SAS_TOKEN>";
        string sourceBlobName = "sample.docx";
        string destinationUri = "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>/destinationFolder/" + "<SAS_TOKEN>";
        string destinationBlobName = "destinationFile1.docx";

        CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sourceUri));
        CloudBlobContainer destinationContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(destinationUri));
        

        CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlobName);
        CloudBlockBlob destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destinationBlobName);

        try
        {
            using (Stream stream1 = sourceBlob.OpenRead(null, new BlobRequestOptions() { UseTransactionalMD5 = true }, new OperationContext() { }))
            {
                document.Open(stream1, FormatType.Docx);


            <CODE_FOR_YOUR_MAILMERGE>


                document.MailMerge.Execute(customers);
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
                document.Save(stream, FormatType.Docx);
                destinationBlob.BeginUploadFromStream(stream, null, null);
                Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Upload successful.");
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Upload failed: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Results:

[image]